# How could I constatly check a value in Python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, python-3.8

So I'm programming a discord bot (using discord.py library) that should manage RPG characters and some other things, I want to manage leveling/xp with the bot. My question is : is there a way that the bot will check every x seconds all the players xp amount ? I know I could write something like if character.xp == xp_amount in every parts that grant xp/create a function that does it and call in these parts, but it is possible to do it "passively" ?

Comment: You could have a thread running that constantly does checks. That would be expensive though if you're checking a lot of users. It would probably be easier in the long run to have all your XP-granting functions use one central function to grant XP, and have that central function also deal with leveling.

Comment: You could run it in a loop in a background thread.

Comment: But @Carcigenicate is correct - this is expensive ... better to rethink your design here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python standard [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html) or [threading](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/threading.html) module to check the value each x second.

Here's a code example for using `threading` module

```py
import time
import threading


VALUE = 10

def check_value(second: int) -> None:
    """Check global variable `VALUE` periodically

    Args:
        second (int): the checking interval
    """

    while True:
        if VALUE == 10:
            print('Value is 10')
        time.sleep(second)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    thread = threading.Thread(target=check_value, args=(2,))
    thread.start()
    # do other stuff here
```